# Copiar dados do Excel para o Drive

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba, google-drive-api

Bom dia,

preciso de seleccionar dados de um ficheiro `Excel` copiar, abrir um ficheiro no `Google Drive` e colar os dados.

```
Sub ActualizarDrive()
'Selecionar Ficheiro
Windows("Lojas_Pendentes_CCTV.xlsx").Activate
'Seleciona dados a cópiar
Sheets("Lista Loja").Select
    Range("B3:T3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.copy

'Abrir Drive e colar dados.
Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe -url https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/xxxxxxx")
    Range("B2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

Está funcionar bem até abrir o **Drive** mas depois não consigo seleccionar nenhuma célula e fazer colar.

O que é necessário fazer para conseguir esse passo?

Obrigado.

Comment: Recomendo utilizar o [API do google spreadsheets](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/exceldocsintegration/excelsheetsv4) ou para interações com janelas, há o [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/) ou para web crawling no chrome, há o Selenium.

Comment: @danieltakeshi agradeço as tuas indicações. Como não percebo nada de VBA e das restantes aplicações ainda não resolvi o problema mas vou continuar a ler sobre eles tentar entender como fazer e caso surja alguma dúvida coloco aqui. Mais uma vez obrigado.

Comment: @danieltakeshi mais uma vez obrigado. Vou "estudar" o Selenium e tentar instalar o Selenium VBA (pc da empresa deve ser preciso autorização do admin).